# How to get a list of keys from a collection of list of properties with key value pairs

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, property-list, keyvaluepair

I have a collection of list of properties with key value pairs as follow screenshot in visual studio.

[image]

UPDATE:

I have the following screenshot if i expend the value(0) on the above screenshot.

[image]

How can I get a list (List (of string) may be?) with Key values from that?

For example, the new list will contain, {Id, Class Name, Forename, Surname, Dob}. No need to filter anything.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your list is a collection of KeyValue pairs then can you not just iterate this collection and build up a new list of strings representing the Key

```
   Dim l2 As New List(Of String)
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In res(0)
        l2.Add(kvp.Key)
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks user1702721. The above code doesn't work. Collection of list of keyvalue pairs is the best description i have. I don't really know what is it that's why I put screenshot above. Can you work out from the screenshot?

Comment: Are you interoperating with VB? Can you expand on the _values(0) item to see what's available in there ?

Comment: Odd..._values definitely looks like a collection of KeyValue pairs. I've modified my earlier suggestion, can you give that a go.

Comment: Thanks .. it doesn't like res(0) .. can't compile. error is `expression is of type "propertybag" which is not a collection type`

Comment: Ok. Any chance we could get a list of the members of the Object type propertybag ?

Comment: OH Thanks your help but i think I am given up now. That object is in an assembly so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.  In this example, the key for each KeyValuePair is a String, but it might not always be, so there is an explicit .ToString() just in case the keys are another type.

```
Dim myList As New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Object))
' add stuff to myList here

Dim keyList as List(Of String)
For Each item In myList
    keyList.Add(item.Key.ToString())
Next item
```

EDIT: Try this:

```
' add stuff to myList here

Dim keyList as List(Of String)
For Each entry in res
    For Each item In entry._values
            keyList.Add(item.Key.ToString())
    Next item
Next Entry
```

Comment: Hi Douglas, Thanks for your answer. But I don't get the .Key from item in my list. Can you work out what type of list it is from the screenshot?

Comment: Try it now.  It looks like some sort of custom type.

Comment: Thanks Douglas, it's really nasty collection of custom property list. we have progress but it doesn't work yet. I got error message saying entry._values isn't accessible because it's Friend. I can't really change that coz it's in a dll. I now notice little Key icon beside _values in the screenprint. Do I still have any option?

Comment: If it is "Friend" then I believe you are out of luck.  That means it is only accessible from within the assembly where it is declared (i.e., your .DLL)

Comment: Thanks Douglas .. i understand a bit more now .. but i can still bind the whole list to the gridview though. And by reading gridview columns, i will get the list that i wanted but so much extra steps.